# JQuery sortable на таблице

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drag-n-drop

Использую плагин sortable на таблице для сохранения порядка строк и последующем обновлении (№позиции и группа) этой строки в БД. Сама таблица содержет группы. Проблема в том, когда строка перетаскивается не понимаю как получить ID группы от куда и куда его перенесли.

Таблица:

```
<table id="sort" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    WID
                </th>
                <th>
                    AID
                </th>
                <th>
                    #
                </th>
                <th>
                    № Вагона
                </th>


            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @foreach (var group in Model.OrderBy(a => a.sprAreas.AreaName).GroupBy(x => x.sprAreas.AreaName))
            {

                <tr class="table-info " id="@group.Key">
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <span class="h3 sortDisable">@group.Key</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                foreach (var item in group)
                {

                <tr>


                    <td class="index" id="@item.LUWID">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LUWID)
                    </td>
                    <td class="index2" id="@item.AreaID">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AreaID)
                    </td>
                    <td class="train">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrainNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sprWaggons.WaggonNumber)
                    </td>



                </tr>

                }

            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
updateIndex = function (e, ui) {
        $(' .train', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
        });
    }


    $("tbody").sortable({
        helper: "clone",
        stop: updateIndex,
        cancel: ".sortDisable",
        scroll: true,
        scrollSensitivity: 100,
        scrollSpeed: 10,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        items: "> tr",
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var new_position = ui.item.index();
            //console.log(new_position)

            if (new_position == 0) {
                $("#sort tbody").sortable("cancel")
            }                
        }

    }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант чтобы сохранять позицию (хоть для каждого юзера) - добавить в бд поле приоритет для каждой записи, в само поле можно добавить атрибут `priority` (например) или можно скрытый ипнут вставлять с приоритетом, и при событии `stop` собирать массив приоритетов и аяксом менять его в бд для каждой записи

Comment: @InDevX не понял вашего комментария, таблица уже сгруппирована по определенному полю. Меня интересует когда я переношу строку из одной группы в другую как мне получить ID группы от куда я взял и куда положил

Comment: id группы прописан в `<td>`?

Comment: @InDevX `<tr class="table-info " id="@group.Key">`, в `<td>` тоже есть, это  `<td class="index2" id="@item.AreaID">`

Comment: вот, значит надо искать сперва id в начале перетаскивания а потом в конце (start, stop события, вроде..).. а искать просто -> `$(item).closest('td').attr('id')`

Comment: @InDevX этим я могу определить какой именно элемент я переношу и его группу, но когда я его переношу из одной группы в другую, мне нужно определить, что он из группы "А" попал в группу "Б" и уже потом обновить у него ID группы

Comment: до сортировки индекс и прочее можно определить только через `start`.. можно, к примеру, в этом же `start` добавлять атрибут с позицией а потом в `update` брать новые позиции и с атрибутов брать старые, и не забывать атрибуты потом удалять